# Vertx-web: where do I place webroot folder?

Tags: java, vert.x

This should be an easy one, but it's not been so far. I've been working with `vert.x 2` for a bit and switched to `vert.x 3` recently. I thought I'd try a simple vertx-web example but can't get past a simple serving up of static files.

My server class contains the following snippets:

```
    HttpServer server = vertx.createHttpServer();
    Router router = ...;
    router.route("/static/*").handler(StaticHandler.create().setCachingEnabled(false));
    server.requestHandler(router::accept).listen(ctx.port);
```

I'm using Eclipse, but have also been trying running `vertx` from the the command line. I'm also using Maven. I have three webroot folders, and `vert.x` can find none of them:

```
myproject/webroot
myproject/src/main/resources/webroot
myproject/src/main/java/webroot
```

Each of those 'webroot's contains an `index.html`, and a `css/base.css` file.

The first one is in my project's root folder. The second is in the Maven resources folder, and the third should be flat-out on my `classpath`. In my Eclipse run config, I added *myproject/src/main/resources/webroot* to the classpath, and I made sure my working directory was set to 'myproject'. When running from the command line, I'm in the *myproject* directory, and my script looks like this:

```
JAVA_OPTS="-Dmyproject.port=8099" CLASSPATH="src/main/java:src/main/resources:target/dependencies/*:target/classes" vertx run com.my.MyProject
```

No matter what, I always get **404s** when I try any of these URLs:

```
http://localhost:8099
http://localhost:8099/
http://localhost:8099/index.html
http://localhost:8099/static/css/base.css
```

Anything else I need to be doing?

Answer (score 7):

The solution I found depends on the answer to the questions: where is the static content going to be at runtime, and from where would you like vertx to serve it?

In my case, the installed file system would be where the static content was located (not in a jar file), and I wanted vertx to serve it from that location so that it could be updated live. So, I disabled classpath resolving in the StaticHandler by setting the JVM system property `vertx.disableFileCPResolving` to `true` at vertx startup.

Then I placed the `webroot` folder under the directory from which the jvm is started. In my case, I'm using scripts that guarantee the jvm's `cwd` is always `<app-root>/bin`, so dropping the content in `<app-root>/bin/webroot` was sufficient. If you can't make guarantees about where the jvm will be started from, it might be tougher, because you may need to pass an absolute path to StaticHandler.webroot() pointing to this fixed location, but I think there is an open issue regarding support for this (see [here](https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-web/issues/204)).

If the static content is going to be packaged into a jar, it's a little simpler. You can add 'webroot' as a resource in the jar and place all the content of interest in there. In this case you don't want to disable classpath resolving, so either set `vertx.disableFileCPResolving` to `false`, or don't set it at all. Now when you run `vertx`, it will find `webroot` in the jar file and extract its contents to `<cwd>/.vertx/.file-cache-<guid>` (where `cwd` is wherever you started the jvm from), and serve the contents from there. Note that this isn't viable if you intend to be able to do live updates to the content, because any changes to the files under that directory will get lost when vertx shuts down, because `vertx-web` will delete that directory. On restart, it will retrieve the original files from the jar resource again, and changes will be lost.

Anyway, hope this helps.

Answer (score 6):

Execute the following code at any breakpoint and it'll tell you the root directory from which it will resolve your resource request:

```
new File("").getCanonicalPath()
```

Request: *localhost:8080/static/script.js*

Handler:

```
router.route("/static/*").handler(StaticHandler.create("webroot"));
```

The file should be in `MODULE_ROOT/webroot/script.js`

Debug all the way into the `StaticHandlerImpl#sendStatic` method to see how your files are being resolved, and use the debug expression window liberally to interrogate the file system.

Answer (score 5):

The default classpath setting worked for me. I used the following hierarchy:

Keep the static file in `main/resources/webroot` directory

```
<AppRoot>/src/main/resources/webroot/static/index.html
```

And initialize vertx as follows:

```
import io.vertx.core.Vertx;
import io.vertx.core.http.HttpServer;
import io.vertx.ext.web.Router;
import io.vertx.ext.web.handler.StaticHandler;

Vertx vertx = Vertx.vertx();

Router router = Router.router(vertx);
router.route().handler(StaticHandler.create());

vertx.createHttpServer().requestHandler(router::accept).listen(8080);
```

Now you can access it from this URL: `http://localhost:8080/static/`

Refer [vertx-web documentation](http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-web/java/#_serving_static_resources) for more info.

Answer (score 4):

Alright, I'll somewhat answer my own question. First, I should point out that I was keying off of the static-content parts of the vertx-web docs (http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-web/js/#_serving_static_resources):

> Any requests to paths handled by the static handler will result in
>   files being served from a directory on the file system or from the
>   classpath. The default static file directory is webroot but this can
>   be configured.
>
> In the following example all requests to paths starting with /static/
>   will get served from the directory webroot:

```
var StaticHandler = require("vertx-web-js/static_handler");

router.route("/static/*").handler(StaticHandler.create().handle);
```

and

> Any requests to the root path / will cause the index page to be
>   served. By default the index page is index.html. This can be
>   configured with setIndexPage.

It seemed to me that if I didn't explicitly define a handler for "/", then index.html would implicitly be served. And it also seemed that just creating a StaticHandler and adding it to the router would suffice for CSS/JS/IMG resources. I think my assumptions were incorrect.

So I added the following, which seem to be what was needed:

first, I told the StaticHandler explicitly to look for a "webroot" folder:

```
router.route("/static/*").handler(StaticHandler.create("webroot").setCachingEnabled(false));
```

then, I explicitly added a route to my router to handle requests to "/":

```
router.route("/").handler(ctx -> {
        Logger.log("Got an HTTP request to /");
        ctx.response().sendFile("webroot/index.html").end();
});
```

Comment: Using Java and I have a webroot folder in resources then used `router.route().handler(StaticHandler.create().setWebRoot("webroot"));`

Answer (score 3):

this solution worked for me, to add more details here is the folder structure for me

```
src
    main
        java
            com
                -- java files with vertx
        resources
            webroot
                html
                js
```

Answer (score 1):

Static files kept in /src/main/resources/assets/

ex: index.html

```
Router router = Router.router(vertx);
router.route("/files/*").handler(StaticHandler.create("assets"));
vertx.createHttpServer().requestHandler(router::accept).listen(8080);
```

Now you can access it from http://localhost:8080/files/index.html

If you look at `router.route("/files/*").handler(StaticHandler.create("assets"));`

When a request matches `/files/` it calls the StaticHandler which specifies `assets` folder as the `web-root`

Answer (score 1):

Directory

```
<AppRoot>/webroot/index.html
```

Vertx

```
router.route("/app/*").handler(StaticHandler.create("webroot").setCachingEnabled(false));
```

URL

```
http://127.0.0.1/app/index.html
```

Add the following Java VM options to enable hot reload

```
-Dvertx.disableFileCPResolving=true
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe people are getting tripped up by the examples in the documentation for serving static resources at http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-web/kotlin/#_serving_static_resources -- some of the answers even go so far as to change the route path, which is not what is desired!

I have raised https://github.com/vert-x3/issues/issues/265 with details.

Among others, OP tried:

```
http://localhost:8099/static/css/base.css
```

That should have worked, the rest of the paths were not valid, and `src/main/resources/webroot` is a good place for packaged-up static resources.